# How to expose domain and repository layer as a service?

Tags: c#, wcf, domain-driven-design, domain-model

I have the following layers currently in my application:

1. API
2. AppService Layer
3. Domain Model
4. Repository

The lower (2) layers (domain and repository) offer almost total reuse across business needs so I thought of exposing at least my domain model as a service, possibly a WCF service. Basically the domain entity data, behavior, and persistance are reusable and I need a way to centrally expose this.

I have read the following ([Sharing domain model with WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468573/sharing-domain-model-with-wcf-service)) and ones similar that indicate for good reason why *not* to expose domain entities directly via WCF. Most of the examples indicate to create data contracts to expose domain data and then have mapping mechnisms to map between the domain and DTO (Data Contract) data. So far so good.

If I have a method in my domain layer like below, how do I expose it via the new WCF service? I thought I would only expose DTOs and therefore how do I also expose the shared/common domain behavior I want to reuse across processes?

```
public int ProcessSomeRule(string param1, string param2)
```

If the answer is to create a method on the WCF service that acts as a proxy still not exposing the `ProcessSomeRule` method directly, I'm cool with that but that spawns another question. The purpose of this abstraction and creating a method on the WCF service named for example `ProcessSomeRuleWCF(string,string)` that just turns around internally and calls the domain method seems to still be coupled and not offer a pure abstraction. It will still be sensitive to signature changes.

I read that by not exposing the methods directly, we can make changes internally without having to modify the contract interface. OK, this sounds great by definition, but if my internal method needs an *additional* parameter and now has the signature `ProcessSomeRule(string, string, string), guess what? My contract interface method will now break because it's missing the 3rd parameter, so my interface *has* to change. Not sure how to do this and still make the abstraction worthwhile?

My repository in the *same* manner is generic and can be used across processes and I want to reuse this layer too. Currently my repository (UoW) Interface is injected into my AppService layer, so I have no idea how this would work if Repository layer was a WCF service.

**Question:** How do I expose the shared behavior of the domain and repository layers and what would the names of these new layers be called? Is the new layer exposing the domain named 'Domain Service' and sit between 'AppService' and 'DomainModel'?

Lastly, if I'm on the wrong path with any of this feel free to guide me back. Thanks!

Comment: 1 question per question is the standard.

Comment: time to leave WCF, use Web Api for REST

Comment: @CuongLe - Web API is used in actually what my *API* layer is using, but I would prefer the speed of TCP calls via WCF for internally exposed services for the purpose of reuse. Be careful with blanket statements on technology use - it's a slippery slope.

Comment: @atconway: just recommendation, if you want to use up TCP, WCF is only way

Comment: The problem with exposing a "domain model" in this way is that you're forcing a non-object-oriented interface over top of the domain model.  I assume you're not using an anemic domain model so you've got lots of behaviour.  To model that in an over-the-wire interface you basically have to reduce it to something like RPC.  Is that really what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I expose the shared behavior of the domain and repository
>   layers and what would the names of these new layers be called?

In the context of a [hexagonal (ports & adapters) architecture](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture), your domain layer would be encapsulated by application services thereby defining the core of your application. Application services implement use cases by delegating to aggregates and domain services and orchestrating access to repositories and infrastructural services. Next, you can "adapt" your application to infrastructure. Having a repository implement an repository interface declared in the domain layer is an example of this. The repository implementation serves as an adapter between the domain and the outside world. Similarly for WCF services, usually called **open-host services** in DDD, they adapt your application to a transport infrastructure. The WCF service, or ASP.NET WebAPI service, would be a relatively thin layer that delegates to application services. Again, the purpose of this layer is only to serve as an adapter. This layer does own the contract that it exposes publicly. In DDD this is referred to as the **published language**. In WCF, for example, it would be defined via `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes. These contracts are how external systems will access your domain. Having a buffer between published contracts and the internal domain is important because they will likely change at different rates and have different consumer requirements.

> Is the new layer exposing the domain named 'Domain Service' and sit
>   between 'AppService' and 'DomainModel'?

No, a domain service is part of the domain layer itself, sitting along with entities, aggregates and value objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think to expose domain object as service is not difficult. but system is really combination service and UI. UI access service, and service can be implemented on different ways: DDD or database-central . so it maybe not a good idea to tell the service caller how we implement our business logic.